# inclusion of sets and inverse function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is it true that for any function $f$, and sets $S_1,S_2$ such that  $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$, if $g$ is the inverse of sets in $S_2$, then $f(g[S_2])\subseteq S1\subseteq g(f[S_1])$? If yes, is there a proof for this statement and if no, is there some counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $f$ must one-to-one for the inverse function to exist. Consider what happens if it is onto $S_2$ or not. (See [Bijection, injection, surjection)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection)